# php/ajax/mysql reload a div without reload the full page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have problems reloading my div, i try different ways but it doesn´t work.
i want to reload every 3 seconds the div= invidual so when a person post something every 3 seconds show the post, 
my code is this

```
<div id="reload">
    <div class="msg wall">

    <?php 

        $u_id = base64_decode($_GET['u_id']);

            $clave = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user1='$user_id' OR user2='$user_id'");
            $clave->execute();
            $llave = $clave->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

                $numero = $llave['hash'];
                $usuario_2 = $llave['user2'];
                $usuario_1 = $llave['user1'];



                $nur = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE group_hash='$u_id'");
                $nur->execute();
                while($row_pos = $nur->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){

                    $msg = $row_pos['msg_content'];
                    $from = $row_pos['writer'];
                    $fecha = $row_pos['msg_date'];


                $user = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id='$from'");
                $user->execute();
                $row_user = $user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

                    $name = $row_user['user_name'];
                    $user_image = $row_user['user_image'];
                    $user_key = $row_user['user_id'];


                    ?>



                    <div id="individual">
                            <span><?php echo $name;?></span><span id="izq"><?php echo $fecha;?></span>
                            <p><?php echo $msg;?></p>   
                    </div>  

            <?php 

                    }

            ?>

        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reload the data of the div, you will have to put the PHP script into a seperate file. Then, in jquery call on the php script, request the latest message and update it, like so: (this is jquery)

```
//function to make the function repeat every 3 seconds
setInterval(updateDiv, 3000);

//Function to make the magic happen
function updateDiv(){
    $.get("urlTo.phpFile.php", function(data){
      $('#individual').html(data);
    });
}
```

On the php file, you'll want to only display the `span` and `p` with the `echo`'s in them, not the surrounding `div`s.